Any ideas for how to recreate functionality of iOS Photos app zoomable grid view in React?
building a mobile-friendly web app in React that is supposed to mimic the layout of the iOS Photos app Grid View:

When you pinch in or out to zoom, as the number of columns change, the item you're pinching on stays centered in the scroll box. It's like all the items in the list re-sort themselves around the item that the pinch is anchored to.
Any ideas for how to approach this? Packages that could be useful?
